# Difference between two Positive Definite Matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I would like to prove the following claim:

Suppose A and B are (square, symmetric) positive definite matrices of dimension nxn (with underlying vector space V).
Then, B-A is positive **semi**-definite IFF $A^{-1}$ - $B^{-1}$ is positive semi-definite.

My attempted approach is to use the variational characterisation of eigenvalues:

$\forall x \in V , x^T(B-A)x \geq 0 \Rightarrow x^TBx \geq x^TAx$

By the variational characterisation of eigenvalues of symmetric matrices,

$\lambda_k(B) = max_{dim(U) = k} min_{x\in U, ||x|| = 1} \ x^TBx \geq max_{dim(U) = k} min_{x\in U, ||x|| = 1} \ x^TAx = \lambda_k(A)$

$\forall \ \  1\leq k\leq n$

If this is true, I think the claim follows just by comparing magnitudes of the eigenvalues of the inverses because A and B are Positive definite, but I am wondering whether the last step above is in fact correct. Does the maxmin above preserve $x^TBx \geq x^TAx$?

Edit: I am not sure if this actually helps with proving the main claim. Any hints?

Comment: Have you noted that $B-A=B(A^{-1}-B^{-1})A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lemma:*
for real symmetric $C\succ \mathbf 0$
$I-C\succeq \mathbf 0$  *iff* $C^{-1}-I\succeq \mathbf 0$
the LHS is true iff all $\lambda^{(C)}\in (0,1]$ and the RHS is true iff all $\lambda^{(C^{-1})}\in [1,\infty)$, but $\big(\lambda^{(C)}\big)^{-1} = \lambda^{(C^{-1})}$ so one condition implies the other

*main argument*
select $C:= B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}$
$B-A = B^\frac{1}{2}\big(I -B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}\big)B^\frac{1}{2} = B^\frac{1}{2}\big(I -C\big)B^\frac{1}{2}$
$A^{-1} -B^{-1} = B^\frac{-1}{2}\big(B^\frac{1}{2}A^{-1}B^\frac{1}{2} - I\big)B^\frac{-1}{2}= B^\frac{-1}{2}\big(C^{-1} - I\big)B^\frac{-1}{2}$

recall that congruence implies same signature and notice
$B^\frac{1}{2}\big(I -C\big)B^\frac{1}{2}$ is congruent to $\big(I-C\big)$ and
$B^\frac{-1}{2}\big(C^{-1} - I\big)B^\frac{-1}{2}$ is congruent to $\big(C^{-1} - I\big)$
and by application of the lemma, the former is PSD *iff* the latter is

Comment: Thanks a tonne, I was breaking my head over this for a while.